# Simplest Way to Solve this Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, absolute-value

> Consider the integral $$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} cos(nx)\big (1-\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{\delta}\big)dx$$

Where $n$ and $\delta$ are constants. Are there any reasonably simple ways to solve this integral? Im not familiar with integrals of absolute value's and the method suggested by an online calculator was very long end tedious.

Comment: Are both $n$ and $\delta$ just arbitrary constants?

Comment: Why this integral? Is your goal calculating some definite integral?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I will update the post with this info.

Comment: @mrsamy Yes the end goal is to evaluate it from $-\delta$ to $\delta$.

Comment: @Pame: that would be easy and you are working on an unnecessary problem. Do you want to edit your question?\\ You should not apply FTC directly.

Comment: For the absolute value: do two separate cases, one where $x>0$ and one where $x<0$.  For the integral from $-\delta$ to $\delta$, observe that the integrand is an even function, so it is twice the integral $\int_0^\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not apply the fundamental theorem of calculus directly. Instead, since the integrand is *even*, you have

$$
\int_{-\delta}^\delta \cos(nx)\big (1-\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{\delta}\big)dx
=2\int_0^{\delta}\cos(nx)\big (1-\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{\delta}\big)dx
=2\int_0^{\delta}\cos(nx)\big (1-\frac{x }{\delta}\big)dx
$$

Now, by linearity, you can work out the following integrals:
$$
\int \cos(nx)dx,\quad \int \cos(nx)\cdot x\,dx
$$
and then combine the results.

---

In general, if you have an even function $f:[-a,a]\to\mathbb{R}$ (that is Riemann integrable),
$$
\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx
$$